# Use of the indefinite article with the name of the language in this way

Tags: articles

> I put back my red pencil, an English book and English notebook in my
>   bag.

Is the above sentence right?

Comment: It may not be wrong, but it sounds off. Better would be "...pencil and an English book and notebook..." or "...pencil, an English book and an English notebook...".

Comment: The juxtaposition of ***notebook*** and unqualified ***book*** is awkward. If it's a ***textbook***, I'd call it that. Otherwise, it's a ***novel***, or whatever.